# Testing this.setState using Jest/ enzyme for react JS - VSC

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to run a test but I'm not sure how to call a set state with the right properties.  I already set the props, beforeEach but unsure if its the correct path. Any help or hint will be extremely helpful. Thanks
This is what I have for testing at the moment :

```
const baseProps = {
 defaultData:{
 url:{},
 method:{},
 name:{},
},
addMetaInformation,
}
```

// Describe and Also Before each have been declared

```
 it ('componentWillReceiveProps',() => {
  const url = baseProps
  wrapper.instance().setState({
     nextProps: {
     url: 'null',
     method :  'test',
     name : 'test name',
  },
})
 wrapper.instance().componentWillReceiveProps(url)
//expect(wrapper.setState()).toContain(url); // not sure about this one
expect(wrapper.instance().setState).toHaveProperty() // mistake
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Here is the code that I am trying to test:

```
      constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  url: null
  }
}
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
if (nextProps.url) {
  this.setState({
    url: nextProps.url
  })
}
if (nextProps.defaultData) {
  if (nextProps.defaultData !== this.props.defaultData) {
    this.setState({
      url: nextProps.defaultData.url,
      method: nextProps.defaultData.method,
      name: nextProps.defaultData.name
    })
   }
  }
}

  handleChange = (e) => {
let localState = Object.assign({}, this.state)
localState[e.target.name] = e.target.value
this.setState(localState)
this.props.addMetaInformation(localState)
```

}

Comment: 1. You don't need to call setState manually. You need to imitate user actions (clicks, entering data, etc.) and check how you component react on these.

Comment: 2. componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated.

Comment: wrapper.instance().setState({
     nextProps: {
     url: 'null',
     method :  'test',
     name : 'test name',
  },
}) remove this correct ? any recomendations based on the test

Comment: When running the test the two lines   this.setState({ is not being covered

Comment: @usererr2591 can you add all code of your component

Comment: @Valerii -  updated... take a look

Comment: you mistake is that you are trying to test methods, but you need to test component behavior. You mount component with some props, then set another props and you are expecting changes in the components (some elements visible, some elements have some text etc.) You don't need to test setState.

Comment: could you give an example based on my previous answer ?

Comment: Look at this example: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/setProps.html